# What could we call a person with deep knowledge in various fields?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences among words describing someone who is expert in many things](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54580/differences-among-words-describing-someone-who-is-expert-in-many-things)

I just wondered, what could we call a person with deep knowledge in various fields? For example, computers, music, sports, etc.

I think I could use *sage*, but it wouldn't be appropriate if someone is experienced in multiple fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess they could be called a *polymath* or *renaissance man* as defined [here.](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-renaissance-man.htm)

Comment: There were serious reservations to *renaissance man*, in a reply to another question earlier.

Comment: polymath is the word used usually, +1 for that. For those curious about the 'math', let us clarify here math means knowledge in general, which perfectly fits. Renaissance man may have many artistic skills also, which I am not sure whether goes along.

Comment: @Kris could you link to that question?

Comment: 1. copy the phrase and paste it in the search box. Voila! 2. For the quintessential slacker: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54580/differences-among-words-describing-someone-who-is-expert-in-many-things

Comment: @Kris, point taken for the meaning "Renaissance" based on the comment there.

Comment: I am voting mainly for renaissance man, since polymath is not widely understood correctly (in the US).  I don't think most people would automatically include computer expertise in their mental image of a renaissance man, but could if given context.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **wise**

> **wise**: having gained a great deal of knowledge from books or experience or both and able to use it well

Comment: Knowledge and wisdom are not synonymous.

Comment: +1 for @Kris, knowing a lot does not make you have wisdom. If that were so, then what would be the value of analysis of knowledge? We know a lot, but how much do we understand?

Comment: @karthik: +1 for "We know a lot, but how much do we understand?". So true in today's world.

Comment: @karthik: Where's my +1 ?

Comment: @Kris, thanks for reminding, intended to, but missed! :)